# NVIDIA graphics not working until startx as root

Tags: nvidia, gdm, 16.10

I fresh installed Ubuntu-Gnome 16.10 and NVIDIA propietary drivers (nouveau runs very slow with my GTX 950) and since then GDM didn't start again (screen flashes in black and does nothing).

I can login in console as my user and `startx` doesn't work (same flashing behaviour), but if I login as root and run `startx` Gnome launches and graphics works smooth. After doing this I can login back as my regular user and running `startx` now works fine (only after root user does). After running `startx` as root I can even restart GDM and everything works fine but I have to do this after every boot.

It looks like launching X as root activates something that otherwise does not. I tried running `sudo modprobe nvidia` but that does not solve it. I also tried reinstalling NVIDIA drivers but didn't work.

My user's Xorg log does't show any errors and the only difference in the log before and after running startx as root is this line:

```
(WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
```

I searched that error but I only find posts related to Bumblebee which is not the case (this is a desktop PC with no Optimus).

Any ideas? Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I think it's caused by this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1632322